# HTML text input will not accept more than 50 characters, even with maxlength > 50

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I have a text input box exactly like so...

```
<input class='text' type='text' name='org' id='org' size='80' maxlength='100' value='<?=$captain['Organization'] ?>'/><br />
```

And I try to type the following into it...

```
Gateway NRA - Staten Island Unit - Great Kills Park
```

And I can't enter anymore after the 'r' in 'Park'.

The maxlength of this input box is 100, which is much more than enough characters to encompass the string I want to type in, but it simply won't take.  I've tried greater maxlength values as well, but still nothing.

I've also noticed that other input boxes where I have much smaller limits, like a box for 'MI' with a limit of 1 character, let's me type in as many characters as I want.  What's going on?

Comment: Do you have any jQuery/Javascript/Plugins that could be messing around with form fields?

Comment: I do, yes.  I had some old events for checking changes on the fly.  Nothing messed with the maxlength attributes that I know of, however, but I guess it could be doing something behind the scenes.  Since I cut out the .keyup and .change events, everything seems to be working as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not enough information here to answer your question.

You may have JavaScript running which is either changing maxlength or enforcing its own control on the input fields and hooking onchange-type events.

Comment: Oddly enough, that was the case.  I briefly cut the JS from my page and the maxlength fields are working as intended.  But the odd thing is that I don't change the maxlength with my JS and I did have some old onChange events running, but I don't see how that would affect it.